# Vue2: prop does not get bound

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Note: I am new to Vue, but prior to posting this I have consulted the docs and looked for other questions. I could not find an answer. I also have the Vue dev tool installed to help debug and could not resolve this seemingly simple problem.

I wanted to make a simple Vue single-file component to test and see if my setup of bundling with rollup was working (e.g. to ensure my understanding of the vue component as modules and exports was correct).

So my simple component consists of two smaller components - either a button with an up chevron or a down chevron. The idea was to have have this sit in the middle of the page and on click move to the next `section` tag.

So far I got this to function works quite nicely (see [demo](http://sumneuron.gitlab.io/vdsm/demos/arrow-to-section/index.html)).

However, I wanted to pass a property to two child component - an offsetSelector. No matter how I try to set the property, I can not get it be set even at the parent level (e.g. `v-bind:offsetSelector=".navbar"`, `:offsetSelector=".navbar"`, `offsetSelector=".navbar"`, etc).

Could someone please help me figure out why this is not getting bound?

## arrow-to-section.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <up :offsetSelector="offsetSelector"></up>
    <down :offsetSelector="offsetSelector"></down>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import down from './section-down.vue';
import up from './section-up.vue';

export default {
  components: { down, up },
  props: [ 'offsetSelector' ],
  data: function () {
    return { }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div > button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
</style>
```

## section-down.vue

```
<template>
  <button type="button" name="button" v-on:click="animateScrollTo">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </button>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  props: [ 'offsetSelector' ],
  data: function () {
    return {
      offset: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {

  },
  methods: {
    setOffset: function() {
      this.offset = this.offsetSelector == undefined
      ? 0
      : $(this.offsetSelector).outerHeight() == undefined
        ? 0
        : $(this.offsetSelector).outerHeight()
    },

    animateScrollTo: function() {

      this.setOffset()


      var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
      var current = undefined;
      var curOffset = this.offset

      console.log('vue-down-offset', curOffset, this.offsetSelector)

      sections.forEach(function(s, i){
        var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop() - curOffset
        var curScroll = $(s).offset().top

        if ( winScroll < curScroll && current == undefined)
        { current = s }
      })

      if (current != undefined) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(current).offset().top - curOffset
        }, 1000, function() {});
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
button {
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(0, 198, 255), rgb(0, 114, 255));
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent 0px solid;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;

  width:32px;
  height:32px;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

i { font-size: 16px; }

button:focus {
  outline: transparent 0px solid;
}
</style>
```

## section-up.vue

```
<template>
  <button type="button" name="button" v-on:click="animateScrollTo">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </button>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  props: [ 'offsetSelector' ],
  data: function () {
    return { offset: 0 }
  },
  computed: { },
  methods: {
    setOffset: function() {
      this.offset = this.offsetSelector == undefined
      ? 0
      : $(this.offsetSelector).outerHeight() == undefined
        ? 0
        : $(this.offsetSelector).outerHeight()
    },

    animateScrollTo: function() {
      this.setOffset()

      var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
      var current = undefined;
      var curOffset = this.offset
      console.log('vue-up-offset', curOffset, this.offsetSelector)

      sections.forEach(function(s, i){
        var winScroll = $(window).scrollTop()
        var curScroll = $(s).offset().top - curOffset

        if ( winScroll > curScroll)
        { current = s }
      })
      if (current == undefined) {
        current = document.querySelector("body")
      }

      if (current != undefined) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(current).offset().top - curOffset
        }, 1000, function() {});
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
button {
  background: radial-gradient(rgb(0, 198, 255), rgb(0, 114, 255));
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent 0px solid;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;

  width:32px;
  height:32px;

  border-radius: 50%;
}


button:focus {
  outline: transparent 0px solid;
}

i { font-size: 16px; }
</style>
```

## demo.html

```
<style media="screen">
    section {
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>


  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light sticky-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../">
          <img src="../../data/vdsm.svg" alt="logo" style="width:150px;">
          <h4 class="lead"> vue components </h4>
      </a>
      <crumbs id="crumbs"></crumbs>
    </nav>
    <arrowToSection id="arrowToSection" offset-selector=".navbar"></arrowToSection>

    <section style="background-color:#5433FF;"></section>
    <section style="background-color:#20BDFF;"></section>
    <section style="background-color:#A5FECB;"></section>
    <section style="background-color:#86fde8;"></section>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="component.js"></script>
```

## component.js

```
let arrowToSection = vdsm.arrowToSection
new Vue({
  el: '#arrowToSection',
  template: '<arrowToSection/>',
  components: { arrowToSection }
})
```

---

## Code base

The repo can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/vdsm).

The two child components:

- /src/scripts/modules/section-up.vue
- /src/scripts/modules/section-down.vue

The component I am working on:

- /src/scripts/modules/arrow-to-section.vue

Demo of the component:

- /demos/arrow-to-section/index.html

Comment: Without looking at the rest of the code (you should include it in the question btw, see [MCVE](/help/mcve) and "how to ask"): the value of v-bind has to be a valid JavaScript expression, and `.navbar` is definitely not one. If you want to pass a member of `this`, drop the dot. Of you want to pass a string, put it in single quotes, like `:prop="'.navbar'"`.

Comment: @Frax the I tried single quotes, but that didn't work.

Comment: You used exactly `:offset-selector="'.navbar'"` and it didn't work? That's surprising. Also, in single-file components you can use `:offsetSelector="'.navbar'"`, that's more readable.

Comment: From what I can see in the code, it's NOT `:offset-selector` but just `offset-selector` (missing colon) ;)

Comment: @Frax I tried the following combinations (I am truncating offsetSelector to oS or o-s for brevity). `:o-s="'.navbar'"`, `v-bind:o-s="'.navbar'"`, `o-s="'.navbar'"`, `:oS="'.navbar'"`, `v-bind:oS="'.navbar'"`, `oS="'.navbar'"`  and none of them work. In the single-file component, I do not want to hardset the property as it might change per use case...

Comment: @AndreyPopov yes, I posted the code as it is, but I am in the corresponding file trying all suggestions for colon and case (e.g. kebab, camel)

Comment: As nobody here can understand how exactly to fix your problem, and as you also have a wrapper before those two arrows, my simplest suggestion would be this - use `{{ offsetSelector }}` to PRINT the property on the screen. You can always use Vue debugger, but this is even simpler. Do that in the `arrow-to-section` file first. See that you're passing the right property to it from the index file. Then do the same for the arrows. THEN investigate your `setOffset` method and everything after that. I kind of think passing property is working, but something else isn't ;)

Comment: Also, try using a simpler name (like, `offsetselector`) to sort out issues with camelCase vs. kebab-case first. Once you have working code, try renaming

Comment: @AndreyPopov in the linked files and repo (what I am testing in) I do that (nothing is shown at  "{{offsetSelector}}" as it is undefined). The vue debugger says that it  offsetSelector is undefined.  Not calling the setOffset method (although it should not affect offsetSelector) does not change anything (I just commented it out)

Comment: @Frax renaming to offsetselector did not change anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it doesn't work

Actually, the answer is pretty trivial: you don't put any props on your `arrowToSection` component. While in your body you have an element confusingly named `<arrowToSection>`, arrowToSection component is not mounted on it - at least not directly. You create arrowToSection component inside the anonymous Vue instance created in `component.js`, here: `template: '<arrowToSection/>'`. And you pass no props to it.

#### How to fix it

To fix it, you need to pass the prop here:

```
let arrowToSection = vdsm.arrowToSection
new Vue({
  el: '#arrowToSection',
  template: '<arrowToSection :offsetSelector="'.navbar'" />',
  components: { arrowToSection }
})
```

Next, you may ask "why not add a prop to this anonymous element, and use the value set in body HTML instead". For which the answer is, props are the way of passing values *between Vue components*. Outside HTML is not a Vue component and you can't pass props from there. The attributes you put on `#arrowToSection` element are just normal attributes (and the whole element gets replaced and arguments lost, btw).

*Later note: [This example in documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) shows attributes being apparently read from the HTML element. It seems somewhat contradictory with my experiment. It's possible that passing props would work if you use full `v-bind:prop="..."` notation instead of `:prop="..."` shorthand.*

#### Alternative solutions with `propsData`

If you really want to use props, you could use [propsData](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData):

```
let arrowToSection = vdsm.arrowToSection
new Vue({
  el: '#arrowToSection',
  props: ['offsetSelector'],
  propsData: {
    offsetSelector: '.navbar',
  },
  template: '<arrowToSection :offsetSelector="offsetSelector" />',
  components: { arrowToSection }
})
```

As you see, this is really contrived and doesn't make sense. However, you don't really need the intermediate component, so, at least in practice, you can use `propsData` this way:

```
let arrowToSection = vdsm.arrowToSection
new Vue(Object.assign({}, arrowToSection, {
  el: '#arrowToSection',
  propsData: {
    offsetSelector: '.navbar',
  },
}))
```

*Disclaimer: I'm not sure using components this way is officially supported. Probably not. But it works.*

Comment: I think you should just delete your question and it's related to your currently wrong implementation of things that are about to work :) So if it's just a typo you found - there's no need for such kind of questions/answers. Good luck!

Comment: @AndreyPopov Sorry, I don't follow. Why do you write it like it it was my question _and_ my answer? And also, actually, I think it's pretty useful, and an interesting problem. Sure, the long code in question is mostly noise, but that's not an issue, anyone with similar problem will look just at the question title and the answer anyway. And the issue here seems to be actual misunderstanding of prop semantics, so calling it a typo is IMO quite out of place.

Comment: @Frax foremost I appreciate your time and assistance with this. I am very new to vue as you might have noticed and not being able to figure out something like this might have turned me away. So thank you. +1 and answer. It seems I do not understand how to properly use single-file components (and to be fair the docs are limited on this matter - mostly link to webpack and I use rollup). Is there a way to not make an anonymous element and just use the vdsm.arrowToSection component?

Comment: @SumNeuron Your use of single-file components seems fine, and using the anonymous instance as a root of Vue structure seems to be a standard pattern, it is actually quite good. Then you don't really need to care what exactly single-file component is, and it's fine (I'm actually not sure whether it's always the same technically). They are mostly just a nice syntax for writing template in `new Vue({...})` expression.

Comment: @SumNeuron I was reading about directives and found an example [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) in which attributes of html element _are_ read. I have to admit I'm quite confused. I tested it in JSFiddle and it didn't work for my props. So either props and directives have a different behavior, or I missed something (or, in the worst case, the example is wrong).

Comment: @Frax huh, I'll have to read more about this and do my own research to see if I can find something. I think, from a quick skim of the docs, that directives can be used for props but shouldn't.  Again, I greatly appreciate all of your assistance

Answer (score 2):

I haven't fully read your repository, but from what I can see the answer can be found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:

Basically the prop in the props list is with `camelCase`, but inside the html attribute it's `kebap-case`. I hope that helps :)

Comment: Note: It actually works both ways. camelCase still gets read from the attribute.

Comment: I tried switching `offsetSelector` to `offset-selector` but that didnt work for me :/

Comment: @webnoob could you please take a look? I am very lost as to why this isn't working :/

Comment: See Frax's comment.

Comment: Actually, you almost hit the real issue, and eventually lead me to the solution: the "prop" was defined in pure HTML and not in a component at all, so Vue never even attempted to read it.